# PEG rule to identify function protoype

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, boost-spirit

I am trying to create a parser that can parse C code. My use case to parse a buffer that may contain a function prototype. I want to push this function name into a symbol table. I am new to Spirit and PEG and I am trying to figure out how I can write a rule that can identify function prototypes.

This is my current implementation:

```
auto nameRule = x3::alpha >> *x3::alnum;
auto fcnPrototypeRule = nameRule >> *nameRule;
auto fcnRule = fcnPrototypeRule >> space >> x3::char_('(') >> -(nameRule % ',') >> x3::char_(');');
```

This is my application code:

```
class Parser {   

    public:
    std::string functionParser(const std::string& input) {
        std::string output;
        x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), fcnRule, space, output);
        return output;
    }
};
```

input is = "extern void myFunction();"
The output is an empty string. I wanted to get the function prototype.

Comment: Boost?  `class`?  This isn't C, it's C++.

Comment: Its a C++ program that analyses C code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `');'` should have been ");"?

Also since you have a skipper (`x3::space` in the call to `phrase_parse`) it doesn't make much sense to:

- also specify `space` in your parser expression (it will never match)
- not wrap the `nameRule` inside a `lexeme` or `noskip` directive. See also [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

So first stab at making it work:

```
std::string functionParser(const std::string& input) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    auto nameRule = x3::lexeme [x3::alpha >> *x3::alnum];
    auto fcnPrototypeRule = nameRule >> *nameRule;
    auto fcnRule = fcnPrototypeRule >> x3::char_('(') >> -(nameRule % ',') >> x3::char_(");");
    std::string output;
    x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), fcnRule, x3::space, output);
    return output;
}
```

However, you'll notice it returns `ndn()` (**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5343711408767b76)**).

I think it's basically caused by the fact that your AS (`std::string`) doesn't match the grammar much. I'd say it looks likeyou mean to "match" instead of "parse" and I'd use `x3::raw` to expose the raw match:

**<kbd>[Live On Colriu](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bd37368dd5c7b3d)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

std::string functionParser(const std::string& input) {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    auto nameRule = x3::lexeme [x3::alpha >> *x3::alnum];
    auto fcnPrototypeRule = nameRule >> *nameRule;
    auto fcnRule = x3::raw[ fcnPrototypeRule >> '(' >> -(nameRule % ',') >> ')' >> ';' ];
    std::string output;
    x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), fcnRule, x3::space, output);
    return output;
}

int main() {
    for (auto s : {
        "extern void myFunction();",
        })
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> " << std::quoted(functionParser(s)) << "\n";
    }
}
```