# How to move results parsed results into a struct using spirit x3

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit

I want to parse an input buffer containing function prototypes into a vector of function prototypes. I have created a function prototype struct that has 3 members: returnType, name and argument list. I am running into a compiler error that complains that it is unable to move the parsed results into the struct. Am I missing something?

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/struct/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;
using boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space;

namespace ast {
struct identifier {
    std::string name;
};

struct argument {
    identifier typeName;
    identifier value;
};

struct function_call {
    identifier name;
    std::list<argument> arguments;
};

struct function_prototype {
    identifier returnType;
    identifier name;
    std::list<argument> arguments;
};
} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::identifier, (std::string, name))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::argument, (struct identifier, typeName) (struct identifier, value))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_call, (struct identifier, name) (struct identifier, arguments))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_prototype, (struct identifier, returnType) (struct identifier, name) (std::list<struct argument>, arguments))

namespace parser
{
    struct identifier_class;
    typedef x3::rule<identifier_class, ast::identifier> identifier_type;
    identifier_type const identifier = "identifier";
    auto const identifier_def = x3::raw[x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_')]];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier)

    struct argument_class;
    typedef x3::rule<argument_class, ast::argument> argument_type;
    argument_type const argument = "argument";
    auto const argument_def = x3::raw[identifier >> identifier];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(argument)

    struct function_call_class;
    typedef x3::rule<function_call_class, ast::function_call> function_call_type;
    function_call_type const function_call = "function_call";
    auto const function_call_def = x3::raw[identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') > ')'];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(function_call)

    struct function_prototype_class;
    typedef x3::rule<function_prototype_class, ast::function_prototype> function_prototype_class_type;
    function_prototype_class_type const function_prototype = "function_prototype";
    auto const function_prototype_def =
    x3::raw[identifier >> identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') > ')'];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(function_prototype)

    auto const functionProtos = function_prototype >> *(function_prototype);
}

namespace Application {
class Parser {

  public:
    void functionParser(const std::string& input) {
        std::vector<ast::function_call> output;
        x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::functionProtos, x3::space, output);
        std::cout << "success\n";
    }
};
} // namespace parser
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Fusion Adapt

One issue is the adaptations: you're supplying types but spelling them as forward declarations of types in the global namespace:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::argument, (struct identifier, typeName) (struct identifier, value))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_call, (struct identifier, name) (struct identifier, arguments))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_prototype, (struct identifier, returnType) (struct identifier, name) (std::list<struct argument>, arguments))
```

It *might* be okay to fix by replacing with e.g. `ast::identifier`, but why bother? You can definitely use the c++11 variation and let the compiler figure out the types:

```
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::identifier, name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::argument, typeName, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_call, name, arguments)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_prototype, returnType, name, arguments)
```

### RAW

The second cinch is `x3::raw[]`. The `raw` directive exposes an iterator range as the attribute, and that's not compatible with the bound attribute type (e.g. `ast::identifier`).

In this particular case, you ARE parsing (compare with my remark from [the previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56150603/85371), where you weren't parsing, and only matching). So you need to match up the synthesized attribute with the target attribute type:

```
auto const identifier_def = x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))];
```

### Single-Element Sequences

There's a lingering issue with Qi/X3 that causes attribute propagation of single-element sequences to get confused. In this case it helps if you simply make `identifier` parse into `std::string` (and fusion *will* correctly assign that to `ast::identifier` from there):

```
auto const identifier_def = x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))];
```

Dropping the rest of the `rawp[]` directives makes it compile:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/272544bbadbee6fd)</kbd>**

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/io.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3/support/ast/variant.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::x3::ascii;
using boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space;

namespace ast {
struct identifier {
    std::string name;
};

struct argument {
    identifier typeName;
    identifier value;
};

struct function_call {
    identifier name;
    std::list<argument> arguments;
};

struct function_prototype {
    identifier returnType;
    identifier name;
    std::list<argument> arguments;
};
} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::identifier, name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::argument, typeName, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_call, name, arguments)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_prototype, returnType, name, arguments)

namespace parser
{
    struct identifier_class;
    typedef x3::rule<identifier_class, std::string> identifier_type;
    identifier_type const identifier = "identifier";
    auto const identifier_def = x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))];
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier)

    struct argument_class;
    typedef x3::rule<argument_class, ast::argument> argument_type;
    argument_type const argument = "argument";
    auto const argument_def = identifier >> identifier;
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(argument)

    struct function_call_class;
    typedef x3::rule<function_call_class, ast::function_call> function_call_type;
    function_call_type const function_call = "function_call";
    auto const function_call_def = identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') > ')';
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(function_call)

    struct function_prototype_class;
    typedef x3::rule<function_prototype_class, ast::function_prototype> function_prototype_class_type;
    function_prototype_class_type const function_prototype = "function_prototype";
    auto const function_prototype_def =
        identifier >> identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') >> x3::expect[')'] >> ';';
    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(function_prototype)

    auto const functionProtos = +function_prototype;
}

namespace Application {
class Parser {

  public:
    void functionParser(const std::string& input) {
        if (0) {
            ast::identifier output;
            x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::identifier, x3::space, output);
        }
        if (0) {
            ast::argument output;
            x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::argument, x3::space, output);
        }
        if (0) {
            ast::function_call output;
            x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::function_call, x3::space, output);
        }
        if (0) {
            ast::function_prototype output;
            x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::function_prototype, x3::space, output);
        }
        {
            std::vector<ast::function_prototype> output;
            x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::functionProtos, x3::space, output);
            std::cout << "success: " << output.size() << " prototypes parsed\n";
        }
    }
};
} // namespace parser

int main()
{
    Application::Parser p;
    p.functionParser("void foo(int a); float bar(double b, char c);");
}
```

Prints

```
success: 2 prototypes parsed
```

### SIMPLIFY

As long as you don't share rules across translation units OR require recursive rules, there is no need for the define/macros. Instead simplify:

```
auto const identifier         = as<std::string>("identifier", x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))]);
auto const argument           = as<ast::argument>("argument", identifier >> identifier);
auto const function_call      = as<ast::function_call>("function_call", identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') > ')');
auto const function_prototype = as<ast::function_prototype>("function_prototype",
    identifier >> identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') >> x3::expect[')'] >> ';');
```

That's using a very simple shorthand to type the rule attirbutes:

```
template <typename T> auto as = [](auto name, auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T> {name} = p; };
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fce3275f5051bb7)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <list>
#include <iostream>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;
using boost::spirit::x3::ascii::space;

namespace ast {
    struct identifier {
        std::string name;
    };

    struct argument {
        identifier typeName;
        identifier value;
    };

    struct function_call {
        identifier name;
        std::list<argument> arguments;
    };

    struct function_prototype {
        identifier returnType;
        identifier name;
        std::list<argument> arguments;
    };
} // namespace ast

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::identifier, name)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::argument, typeName, value)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_call, name, arguments)
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(ast::function_prototype, returnType, name, arguments)

namespace parser
{
    template <typename T> auto as = [](auto name, auto p) { return x3::rule<struct _, T> {name} = p; };

    auto const identifier         = as<std::string>("identifier", x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))]);
    auto const argument           = as<ast::argument>("argument", identifier >> identifier);
    auto const function_call      = as<ast::function_call>("function_call", identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') > ')');
    auto const function_prototype = as<ast::function_prototype>("function_prototype",
        identifier >> identifier >> '(' > -(argument % ',') >> x3::expect[')'] >> ';');

    auto const functionProtos = +function_prototype;
}

namespace Application {
    class Parser {

        public:
            void functionParser(const std::string& input) {
                std::vector<ast::function_prototype> output;
                x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser::functionProtos, x3::space, output);
                std::cout << "success: " << output.size() << " prototypes parsed\n";
            }
    };
} // namespace parser

int main()
{
    Application::Parser p;
    p.functionParser("void foo(int a); float bar(double b, char c);");
}
```

Which also prints

```
success: 2 prototypes parsed
```

Comment: I must say, I like what you did with the 'as' wrapper and how it puts the attribute out in front where you can see it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent explanation and for taking time to code it up.